# PEP8 checker testcase in Django 1.8 project

Tags: django-testing, pep8, django-1.8

I'm trying to add pep8 checker testcase to my Django 1.8 project. I found this package: https://github.com/TracyWebTech/django-test-pep8

If I followed the README.md install guide except the INSTALLED_APPS part, because in my project it's a list of strings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test_pep8',
)
```

So I added it as a string without importing it in settings.py.

When I run `./manage.py test` the stylecheck is not working. If I run `./manage.py test test_pep8` it works.

My assumptions are:

- The problem is with this INSTALLED_APPS list, probably the tests are
  not detected based on this list, because if I add a new app, I don't
  need to add it here, but it's tests are running.
- The structure of test_pep8 is not compatible with a Django 1.8 project     (admin.py and migrations may be necessary (based on this [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) under `python manage.py startapp polls`). - I tried to add admin.py and migrations package, but I might did something wrong.

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub issue for this problem here: https://github.com/TracyWebTech/django-test-pep8/issues/1

Which solves it using an additional test-file containing:

```
from test_pep8.tests import PEP8Test

__all__ = [
    'PEP8Test',
]
```

Comment: Yes, that was made by me, after I figured it out (And I left this question here..)